# How to order the files in src folder

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I'm trying to put Lesson10 file in the bottom and I can't.

[image: Screenshot of folders in IntelliJ IDE]

Comment: It is already sorted, as 1 come before 3.

Comment: Folders don't have order. You can sort the files according to something (in this case it seems to be lexical ordering), but there's no "beginning of folder" or "end of folder". So forget about it and start writing code (or rename your files to `Lesson01` etc.).

Comment: The list is sorted using a simple string comparision. This makes 'Lesson1xxx' come before 'Lesson2yyy' regardless of what 'xxx' and 'yyy' are.

Answer (score 0):

Folders are sorted in lexical order which means `Lesson10` comes before `Lesson2`. You can solve this by adding a zero before the lower numbered lessons: `Lesson02`, `Lesson03`, etc. As a note, if you get to lesson 100 you would need to add an additional zero before every prior lesson.